# Flickering graphics on a section of LCD screen

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

The graphics on my LCD are flickering on only a portion of my LCD. I feel that this is a hardware issue. The issue began back in October whenever I was putting a lot of computing load on my laptop. It typically would disappear in a day or two, however, this time around it has been over two weeks and the graphics glitch is still present. If I connect to an external display, everything work fine hinting to me that it may be a hardware issue. Is there any way that I can salvage my laptop LCD screen or does it seem like I may have to replace it? Thanks.

[image: Flickering graphics on a strip of my LCD]

Comment: usually due to a graphics chip that has overheated and melted (disconnected) some of the solder points to the motherboard, you can try to carefully heat the chip and reflow the solder but is tricky business.

Comment: Thanks @Moab. I turned my laptop upside down and let it run with a high CPU load to try to remelt the solder. The flickering problem has not been fully resolved, however, I do see significant improvement. If need be, I'll resolder the GPU and reapply thermal paste when I find time.